# VBA - Execute string as command in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

In the last 30 minutes I am trying to execute a string in VBA as a command. The command is like this and it runs ok:

```
activesheet.chb_g_ba1.visible = true
```

What I am trying to do is to set "chb_g_ba1" as a variable, because there are "chb_g_ba2", "chb_g_ba3", etc as well.

What I have tried so far - things like:

```
dim l_counter as long: l_counter = 1
Evaluate (CStr("me.chb_g_ba" & l_counter & ".visible = true"))
```

Or even Eval

```
Eval (CStr("me.chb_g_ba" & l_counter & ".visible = true"))
```

Eval is a function in MS Access VBA, but obviously it is not present in Excel. Pretty much my question is extremely similar to this one:[VBA how to run a string as a line of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24956527/vba-how-to-run-a-string-as-a-line-of-code), but it is for Excel, not for Access.

So, any ideas are welcomed! :)

Comment: Assuming that's a control on the sheet, use: `activesheet.oleobjects("chb_g_ba1").visible = true`

Comment: No, other than actually writing the code to a module.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I have deleted my answer just to double check it. But it really works. The Question was - "Is it possible to do it like Eval()"

Comment: I don't know what answer you are talking about. There is no Eval or equivalent for this in Excel VBA. Nor can I think of a good reason to need one, to be honest.

Comment: I meant the comment, before your second comment.

Comment: @Rory do you know why the following does not work - activesheet.oleobjects("chb_g_ba1").value = true

Comment: You need to access the object contained in the OLEobject: `activesheet.oleobjects("chb_g_ba1").Object.value = True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to [CPearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx):

There is a way to do that but we have to add a new module dynamically with required code and delete while finished.

References: Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3

```
Sub test()
    Set VBComp = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_StdModule)
    VBComp.Name = "NewModule"
    Set VBCodeMod = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("NewModule").CodeModule
    Dim l_counter As Long
    l_counter = 1
    With VBCodeMod
        LineNum = .CountOfLines + 1
        .InsertLines LineNum, _
        "Sub MyNewProcedure()" & Chr(13) & "UserForm1.chb_g_ba" & l_counter & ".Visible = True" & Chr(13) & "End Sub"
    End With
    'run the new module
    Application.Run "MyNewProcedure"
    UserForm1.Show
    'Delete the created module
    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove VBComp
End Sub
```

Comment: It also requires trusted access to the vb project, which is not set by default.

Comment: Thanks, Karthick. But it looks like overkill. I just wanted to eliminate writing 10 lines of code.

Comment: you can add more lines by using the chr(13)

Comment: I mean, the whole idea was not write If Else 10 times. But thanks :)