# Runtime error 2482 while executing string as code

Tags: vba, ms-access

So I'm attempting to change the value of a textbox on a form with VBA code.

I'm actually doing this by [running a string as code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24956610/6327721) so I can loop through a number of textboxes that are named similarly (RacewayOrder1, RacewayOrder2, etc...) and populate them all one at a time.  So my code looks like this:

```vb
Private Sub FillRow(ByVal OrderNumber As Integer)

Dim tempstr As String
tempstr = "RacewayOrder" & OrderNumber & " = " & OrderNumber
Eval (tempstr)

End Sub
```

However, I am getting runtime error 2482 "Database cannot find the name 'RacewayOrder1' you entered in the expression"

I have verified that this isn't a typo, as I copied the text box's name directly into vba, but that doesn't seem to help.  I even created the tempstr variable so I could inspect the code it is attempting to run, but that hasn't helped at all either.

To make matters more annoying, I debug.printed tempstr and pasted it in as a command, and it works fine.

[image]

Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `Eval()` to assign a value to your text box.  If you overcome the `RacewayOrder1` not found problem, `Eval()` will treat your string expression as a test for equality, not as a value assignment.

Forget about `Eval()` for this and simply reference the text box by name in the form's *Controls* collection:

```
Me.Controls("RacewayOrder" & OrderNumber).Value = OrderNumber
```